# jQuery checkboxes - explanation

Tags: jquery, html

I had made a small form with no. of checkboxes... When I click on "Check all"-checkbox, then all the checkboxes are checked automatically. This is my code, but I have taken the following code from the internet only.
Although it's working but as I am new to jQuery, I don't understand what this code does. Can someone please explain?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#checkAll").change(function () {
          $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
          alert("Yoy have checked all");
        });
      });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <p><label><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll"/> Check all</label></p>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>All Checkboxes</legend>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" /> Option 1</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" /> Option 2</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" /> Option 3</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" /> Option 4</label></p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: please explain me that how the script is working in above program

Comment: `$("input:checkbox")` selects all input elements of type `checkbox` and simply adds the attribute "checked" to all of them. `$(this).prop("checked")` is a way to check if that checkbox is checked or not. So in other words, the code will check if the checkbox is checked (true or false) and it will use that result to either uncheck or check the checkbox.
And this routine will be executed for each input element of type checkbox.

Comment: jQuery has a fantastic reference which you can use to look up any selectors, properties and methods you're unsure of. http://api.jquery.com

Comment: is it possible to know that weather a particular checkbox say checkbox no.3 is checkrd or not,if checked then return true else false....?If so,then please tell

Comment: you need to class and use index to determine which checkbox you are referring to. or an `ID`.

Comment: if you want to use the 3rd checkbox, you could use `$("input:checkbox").eq(2)". This function gets the element based on the index of that element, making 2 the third element of type input:checkbox. It's a zero-based index (starting at 0 = first element)

Comment: ok @Jorrex..I am tryng..tx again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simple, first in this code simple when you check the first( check all) check box then the change event is that occured and the next line $("input:checkbox)"selector select the all checkbox.
    And the prop function check the property checked
$(this).prop("checked"); add the checked proerty in checkbox and all the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is script with comments:

```
// When document is ready, run function
$(document).ready(function(){

    // When 'change' event is triggered on element with id 'checkAll'
    // run function 
    $("#checkAll").change(function () {

        // Set property 'checked' of all inputs with type 'checkbox'
        // to state that #checkAll input has
        $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));

        // Alert 'Yoy have checked all'
        alert("Yoy have checked all");
    });

});
```

You can see it in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mkLdn1rb/).

If you are not very familiar with *jQuery* or *JavaScript*, please check some beginner tutorials on YouTube or just Google it. There are plenty of video tutorials that explain basic *HTML* and *jQuery* stuff which should be very useful.

**Note that *stackoverflow* is not a place where other developers will explain what some snippet of code does.**

Hope this was useful :)